# Entity Framework 4.1 can't get records from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

```
var entity = _db.Connections.Where(x => x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

`Connections` has another `List<Messages>` inside it.

This doesn't return the `List<Messages>` from the database if it is called more than once. If I debug the code, the data gets retrieved if I call `Take(_count).ToArray()`, but `List<Messages>` still doesn't get retrieved.

So my simple question is how do I force Entity Framework to go and get the ACTUAL data from database ?

Thanks, any tips are appreciated

```
public interface Connection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Messages> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand: Your object `entity` is loaded from DB but the collection property `list` within this object is null, right? And you have this problem only when you query the second time, and the first time it works? Are you using lazy loading? It might be easier to understand if you could show your `Connection` class with the `list` property inside.

Comment: I`m doing normal one to many relationship , problem is the second time i query against messages from the connection object , messages doesn't get to be retrieved from database,

Comment: You mean `class`, not `interface` in your edit, right? *"i query against messages from the connection object"*: Can you exactly show the code of the query you are doing?

Comment: If you could add actual code of all the calls you do and then say what properties are null and which aren't in each call, that would help immensely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your Messages property to

> `public virtual ICollection<Messages> { get; set; }`

before Entity Framework will actually populate it when pulling it back from the database.

Comment: For the record adding virtual does not actually make it populate it when pulling back from the database. The virtual keyword is just necessary to implement lazy-loading (which is on by default in EF). The property will not be populated until you make a call against it and another query is made.